# Best spout shape to ensure minimal water sticks after pouring?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics

I have a tipping bucket rain gauge whose accuracy I feel could be improved by redesigning the shape of the bucket lip. In particular, after tipping, there tends to be a bead of water (approx 0.1 - 0.2ml) attached to the lip of the bucket. The bucket tips with only 4.2mls of water and that is collected close to the pivot point so that a 0.1ml drop at the lip of the bucket (as far from the  pivot as you can get) is not insignificant and adds quite a bit of random noise to the measurements.

As seen in the image the current bucket lip is a smooth scallop shape and (although difficult to see in the image) the lip profile is a flat downward sloping bevel. Essentially the bucket has a similar shape and lip profile as a curved woodworking chisel.

My thoughts are that there must be some modification that I could make to the lip to encourage that drop to fall off and follow its brethren down the drain? I've had many different ideas to try: cutting a valley in the centre of the lip, having a thin protrusion sticking out from the lip, or maybe a fine sawtooth edge would work to draw the drop off? I have also thought that having a semi-circular rather than bevelled lip profile would work better to draw the drop over the edge?

The problem I have is that I have no easy way of testing any of these hypotheses. I only have one tipping bucket and can't afford to buy more just to experiment on so I don't want to go modifying it unless I am reasonably sure that it will be an improvement.

Google searches have brought up plenty of results on hydrophobic surfaces and the like (which would be fantastic but are a little beyond my reach) but nothing on surface shape or edge geometry.

Obviously I'm looking for ideas for modifications that I can easily make at home but any links to theoretical info on the subject would be welcome also.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvHs1.jpg)

Comment: coat it with a water repellent?

Comment: These drops are held by the surface tension between solid and liquid interface. So, If possible, increase the radius of curvature of the channel/bucket lip (more flattened). This will not annihilate surface tension but could reduce to a value which may help you to improve the situation.

Comment: Also, There is a post which is exactly opposite to your situation. But the physics is same. https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23014/whats-the-best-shape-for-inducing-condensation/23085#23085 If you need more, I could further explain this to your situation.

Comment: @SolarMike I thought of that also. I briefly tried this https://www.inoxmx.com/products/mx4-lanox-lanolin-lubricant/ as it is supposed to give a long lasting water resistant coating and it work well for a short while, however it wore off relatively quickly. I have read some people use car wax and I may try that but I figured it was better to fix some other shortcomings in the design and improve the shape of the buckets as much as possible first.

Comment: Even try rubbing a raw potato on it - that changes the situation - works on windscreens... the raindrops move easier with the wind.

Comment: @mustang so are you saying my assumption was correct and it would be better to have a semi-circular lip rather than the current bevelled edge? Would there be any merit in having a fine, almost needle point in the middle of the lip to attract the drop from the main funnel surface through adhesive forces and then the drop would fall off better as there would not be enough surface for it to sit on?

Comment: @solarmike lol, please tell me you don't rub a potato on your windscreen?! Doesn't it get all starchy? I'll keep that one for when all else fails...

Comment: Where do you think they got the idea for RainEx... etc

Comment: @tb75 Yes. Semi-circular will be better than bevel in this context. But I am doubtful about the needle-like tip Since I could not really imagine the size and shape. Also, needle-like tip holds the droplets until the self-weight breaks the surface tension.

Comment: In the distant past I recall reading some articles on teapot spout design - the search there was for no drips, but the basic problems are the same.  It's a nasty mix of fluidity, surface energy, flow vortex, and so on.

Comment: Adjust the position of the apparatus so that the tip bucket lip touches the bottom cup. Then you can work on increasing the surface tension of the cup, which doesn't mess with the sensitive bits. I take it that it works by counting the tips, not measuring the accumulated water. If that is the case, try a tiny wick or sponge in the cup to sop the drop off.  The frazzled end of a spun nylon rope should do.

Comment: @philsweet I thought of that also. I actually tried with a small loop of stainless steel wire (to avoid rusting or rotting issues with other materials) with the end poking up and the threads slightly loosened to act as a wick as you suggest. I haven't fully discounted the idea but I had some issues where the drop would not completely dislodge and would bridge between the bucket and wick and thus acting as an even heavier (and more variable size) drop. I have shelved that idea for now as it seems more fiddly to get working consistently and more likely to be affected by dirt, etc. over time.

Comment: FWIW, the conventional wisdom of potters is that teapot spouts should have a very sharp lip but more or less reversed from yours so the water flows down to a very sharp edge before it drops off. A rounded shape will let the water dribble down the outside due to surface tension

Comment: Interesting article about research on this topic: https://arstechnica.com/science/2019/05/dribble-no-more-physics-can-help-combat-that-pesky-teapot-effect/